# Changing mysql configuration file

Tags: mysql, my.cnf, dedicated-server

I have dedicated server having centos 5, I had installed mysql in it. now the problem is that I will not able to create more than 250 table inside one database. I know that it can be increased by changing my.cnf file, but I don't know what code I need to change. How I connect and get my.cnf file. I don't know but I had had got it in ssh using port 22 and by command

```
vi my.cnf
```

Please help me. Below is the content I got using above method.

```
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
# Default to using old password format for compatibility with mysql 3.x
# clients (those using the mysqlclient10 compatibility package).
old_passwords=1

# To allow mysqld to connect to a MySQL Cluster management daemon, uncomment
# these lines and adjust the connectstring as needed.
#ndbcluster
#ndb-connectstring="nodeid=4;host=localhost:1186"

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid

[ndbd]
# If you are running a MySQL Cluster storage daemon (ndbd) on this machine,
# adjust its connection to the management daemon here.
# Note: ndbd init script requires this to include nodeid!
connect-string="nodeid=2;host=localhost:1186"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had tried so many methods and finally got the answer. It can't need to edit my.cnf file. It can be done using config.inc.php file which is located inside phymyadmin folder of dedicated server, where we can insert below line:

```
$cfg['MaxTableList'] = 250;
```

Here you can set the maximum number of table you want inside one db.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL does not have a limit of the number of tables in one database.  What error are you getting?

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/database-count-limit.html